# I want to make multiple selection using a href

Tags: multipleselection

Hi I want to make multiple selection a href.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qJTi.jpg]

Please help me to how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for help. I am using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for the below mentioned answer:

`<select onchange="location.href=this.value;">
    <option value="http://some_url/1.jpg">1.jpg</option>
    <option value="http://otherurl/2.jpg">2.jpg</option>
 </select>`

Comment: Can't I do it with plain text(CSS effects will be added)? I don't want to use Images. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Hi Xerius,Thanks for your answer. Can you please help me the do with out images?

Thanks, Ramana Kumar CH

Comment: I cannot view the link in your question. Can you please resend your question showing what you want.